# HP Envy x360 M6-ar004dx Ubuntu 16.04 touchscreen not working

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, touchscreen, hp-envy

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Envy and can't get the touchscreen working. No response when I touch the screen, even after reboot. I've seen a couple of other topics on this but none that solved my issue so I apologize if a solution is already out there somewhere.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c8:038e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1576
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1577
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev c8)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157c
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157b
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1578
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157d
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 157a
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1570
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1571
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1572
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1573
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1574
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1575
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
```

`xinput --list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys
```

As suggested by another post:

```
username@username-HP-ENVY-x360-m6-Convertible:~$ sudo rmmod hid_multitouch
[sudo] password for username: 
rmmod: ERROR: Module hid_multitouch is not currently loaded
```

Tried this and as expected no effect:

```
xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 0 && xinput set-prop 11 "Device Enabled" 1
```

I don't know much about Ubuntu or drivers so I don't really know what to do with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  HP Envy x360 m6-ar004dx...touchscreen no worky on Arch Linux (latest trunk), nor Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  As best I can tell, this thing has an ELAN0732 I2C touchscreen controller (`/sys/dev/bus/i2c/...`).  Manually loading (`modprobe`) `hid_multitouch`, `elants_i2c`, etc., has yielded no progress.  Touchscreen works fine in Windows.  Not sure where to go from here, other than wait for the mfr. to release a driver, or someone who knows touchscreen controllers to fix `hid_multitouch`.

Also, for those of you with this model laptop...perform an `lsmod | grep -i acer` and if you see a module listed, you should uninstall and blacklist it.  `NetworkManager` will once again be able to control your WiFi :P